# JQuery/JavaScript: Using a random number generator as a setInterval() timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a novice with JS/Jquery and I'm trying to have an image appear at a random place at a set interval (like a whack-a-mole game), which is currently set to repeat every 3 seconds, but I want to have the image appear at a random time between 1 and 2 seconds.

Here is the code I'm having issues with:

```
var roleTime = Math.floor(Math.random()*(2000-1000));
        setInterval(function(){
            randRole();

        }, 3000);
```

I try to use the roleTime variable in place of the 3000ms but it just causes the image rapidly fill the div that it is contained in.

Comment: `1000-2000` is a negative number, which means you are passing `-1000` as the interval time

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` can only use a single interval value (roughly the same interval between callbacks). But you can use a repeated `setTimeout` instead:

```
function cycle() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        randRole();
        cycle();
    }, 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000));
}
cycle();
```

Also note how that calculates a random number between 1000 (inclusive) and 3000 (exclusive): It takes 1000 then adds a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 2000 (exclusive).